# search functionality in navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've added a search field in the navbar (using Bootstrap3), but i can't get it to work except if i'm on the products' page. I've tried initializing (as seen in the welcome controller but i don't get it what i'm doing wrong ...). I can't get both to work without breaking something ...
The homepage throws me this :

```
Couldn't find Category with 'id'=#<Category::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x5623a70>
```

While the Category page throws me :

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :category_id=>nil, :controller=>"products"} missing required keys: [:category_id]
```

my nav is :

```
 <%= form_tag(category_products_path(@category), :method => "get", id: "search-form", class: "navbar-form navbar-left") do %>
        <div class="form-group">
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :class => 'btn btn-default',:name => nil%>
      <% end %>
```

routes

```
resources :categories, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :products, only: [:index, :show]
end
```

controllers

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    def index 
        @category = Category.all
        @products = Product.all
    end
end
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_product, only:[:show]
    def index
        @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
        if params[:search]
            @products = @category.products.search(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page=>10, :page=>params[:page])
        else
            @products = @category.products.paginate(:per_page=>10, :page=>params[:page])
        end
    end

    def show
    end

    private

    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end
end

class CategoriesController < ApplicationController    
    before_action :set_category, only: [:show]
    def index
      @categories = Category.all
    end

    def show
      @products = @category.products
    end

    private

    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Comment: in `WelcomeController` try to change `@category = Category.all` to `@categories = Category.all`

Comment: oh thanks my bad, this solved the welcome page. however now both throw this error : No route matches {:action=>"index", :category_id=>nil, :controller=>"products"} missing required keys: [:category_id]. I don't see where i should actually initialize this

Comment: It's look like you haven't `:category_id` in permitions of `product`

Comment: that is set in the admin controller, that is not the issue here. the admin panel works fine

Comment: do you still have form_tag(category_products_path(@category)? shouldnt that be @categories now? but if that is the case, you cannot have many categories pointing to one path.

Comment: no but again that doesn't change anything, because i'm using it for the products in the welcome view. I just can't find a solution to search for the products from the welcome page. from the products page it works ...